# Modifications required to transform a standalone substrate node using aura + staking into a polkadot parachain

Tags: substrate, polkadot, cumulus

I have a few questions about Cumulus:

1. For a standalone substrate chain to work with a relay chain, there must be three modifications made (besides collator selection mechanism): a) The parachain info pallet along with the register_validate_block! macro, in the runtime b) No grandpa pallet c) The collator service.
   While a) and b) seem to be fairly easy to comprehend and implement, c) i do not fully understand.
   With regards to c), i) Is the node/src/service.rs the only thing in the node that must be changed? ii) Once the node/src/service.rs is changed for a non-live solo substrate chain to morph it into a parachain, will it still be able to function as a solo independent chain iii) Since the node/src/service.rs is not a part of the wasm runtime, how would a live solo substrate chain make the forkless transformation to becoming a live parachain, and back again if required?
2. Regarding collator/validator selection: For a solo substrate chain that works on aura (with the staking and session pallet), is adding and configuring the aura-ext pallet and the collator-selection pallet, the only two things required for switching to a parachain that uses cumulus with collators?
3. Is authority-discovery relevant here?

Comment: Have you followed the parachain tutorial in the docs? https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/v3/cumulus/start-relay/

I think rather than trying to modify a working solo-chain into a working parachain, you should simply take the unique runtime you have developed, and build that on top of the cumulus template, which is already a known working parachain.

Comment: How would that affect our ability to function independently, If we decided to not be a parachain in the future?

Comment: Also that seems to involve using substrate V4 that is still in dev.

Comment: Most Substrate development happens in the runtime, and thus should work on a solo chain or parachain without much concern. Being a parachain in general is more restrictive than being a solo chain, so as long as you can build a working parachain, it will basically always work as a solo chain. Using the latest substrate is the right thing to do, independent if it is "dev"